# Change event listener for `SlideToggle` of Skeleton (Svelte UI kit)

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, svelte

Using `SlideToggle` of Skeleton, I am creating a toggle switch like this.

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { SlideToggle } from '@brainandbones/skeleton';
    let is_checked: boolean = false;
</script>

<div class="page-container">
    <SlideToggle bind:checked={is_monitoring}>{is_checked ? 'Activated' : 'Disabled'}</SlideToggle>
</div>
```

How can I get on-change event instead of polling `is_checked` status manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a change event to the toggle. This event listener will get forwarded to the underlying element in the slider.

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { SlideToggle } from '@brainandbones/skeleton';

    let handleOnChange = (e) => {
       // your subroutine goes here
    }
</script>

<SlideToggle on:change={handleOnChange}>Label</SlideToggle>
```

More info under the 'events' tab on [this page of the skeleton docs](https://www.skeleton.dev/components/slide-toggles).

Comment: `checked` is a boolean prop declared in [`SlideToggle` source code](https://github.com/Brain-Bones/skeleton/blob/master/src/lib/components/SlideToggle/SlideToggle.svelte).

Comment: Did you want to use the `on:click` handler instead then? This will run your callback when the checkbox is clicked so you can control the if the slider is "checked"

Comment: `on:click` will also be triggered when the element is disabled. In that case, need to check its disabled status also.  I was looking for if there is any solution for  `on:change` like implementation.

Comment: I just tested this, and it worked, thanks. I also added more information on my own answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just discovered that the `on:change` event is forwarded the inner `input` checkbox element. Thus, `on:change` was already working out of the box.

Here is the discussion on [Skeleton Issues](https://github.com/Brain-Bones/skeleton/issues/562).

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import { SlideToggle } from '@brainandbones/skeleton';

    let checked: boolean = false;

    function onChange(e: any) {
        console.log(checked);
    };
</script>

<SlideToggle on:checked={checked} on:change={onChange}>Label</SlideToggle>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the accepted answer: if you want the value inside the `handleOnChange`, you can use:

```
function handleOnChange(e: any) {
    const target = e.target as SlideToggle;
    console.log(target.checked);
  }
```